# Android Emulator of android studio keep glitching

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-emulator, nvidia

[Glitch-Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrcmQ.png) The screen keeps glitching and pixels going dark whenever I'm working on android studio's android virtual device. Help me to fix this, please.
[Glitch-Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/111Ul.png)

Comment: what is your system specification?

Comment: Mostly cause of low end system , your ram should be 8gb or above , 2.50ghz or above processor (GPU). try to upgrade system or try to us other emulator like bluestack etc...

Answer (score 0):

I have recently the same issue in emulator, Nexus 5 (Android O). I have go to Android Virtual Device Manager and Wipe User Data and it solved my Problem.
[image]

or you can try this :
Open AVD manager, CLick on the drop-down arrow:

select >> wipe data after that u can select >> cold boot now.

Comment: Bad Luck bro didn't work for me. If I'm setting my Emulator Performance graphics to Software GLEs2.0 then it's working fine but too slow and lagging.

Comment: my recommendation is to use actual device

Comment: Thank You bro I think that's the only option now.